# python calling a super class method in a subclass method with arguments=None

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to create a class called ShoppingCart with a method remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price).

I want to create a subclass Shop of superclass ShoppingCart and 
In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one.

```
class ShoppingCart(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.total = 0
      self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
      self.total += price * quantity
      self.items[item_name] = quantity

    def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
      if quantity> self.items[item_name]:
        quantity = self.items[item_name]
        del self.items[item_name]
      else:
        new_quantity =  self.items[item_name] - quantity
        self.items[item_name] = new_quantity
      self.total-=quantity*price 

    def checkout(self, cash_paid):
      if cash_paid < self.total:
        return "Cash paid not enough"
      balance = cash_paid - self.total
      return balance

class Shop(ShoppingCart):
    def __init__(self):
      self.quantity = 100
      #ShoppingCart.__init__(self)
      super(Shop,self).__init__()

    def remove_item(self, item_name=None, quantity=None, price=None):
        self.quantity -= 1
        super(Shop, self).remove_item(item_name,quantity,price)
```

Comment: Do you want to call `ShoppingCart`'s `remove_item` function also from inside `Shop`'s, or do you just want to decrement the quantity?

Comment: i just want to decrement the quantity

Comment: If you dont need arguments in `remove_item` then you can write it like this : `def remove_item(self)` or like this : `def shop_remove_item(self)` if you want it to call parent's `remove_item` with None values.

Comment: @t.m.adam thank you i worked

Comment: You are welcome